# Http to https redirect not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, server

My nginx.conf file looks like this

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen      [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
   }


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;       
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

    server_name serverip;
    return  444;
}

  server {
        listen       443 ssl ;
        server_name  server.server.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;       
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

  location / {

         auth_basic "Restricted Access";
         auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

           proxy_pass http://localhost:8980;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

     }

}
```

I have tried various versions of server block but its not redirecting from http to https

like the following ,with most of the answers present here ,its just not working

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen      [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name server.server.domain;
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
   }


server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen      [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name server.server.domain;
         return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; 
   }
```

I am accessing my application with domain name and its working if I put https:// server.server.domain ,but when I put http://server.server.domain it just times out with no response

Comment: If it times out, it suggests that the browser is not connecting to the server. Is there a firewall blocking port 80?

Comment: Nice point ,I will check it.